# Can I decompile Genero .42r/.42m files?

Tags: decompiling, 4gl, genero

I have an old project that was developed by Genero Studio, but I don't have the source code files (`.4gl`) of the project.

I only have the executable files (`.42m`/`.42r`). Is there a way I could view the code of those files and/or modify them?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer No, there is no single tool or command.  Contact your local 4Js support contact for techniques and clues as to how to piece it back together.